# Android Tab icon for 4.0 and later

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-style-tabhost

I want to set icon on a tab. My codes are right and I am sure.Is it a problem because of the version of android? I looked lots of codes but all of them are the same.The codes are;

```
package com.mesutemre.androidtabkullanimi;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityGroup;
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TabHost tabhost = getTabHost();
    tabhost.setup();
    tabhost.addTab(tabhost
            .newTabSpec("tabindis1")
            .setIndicator("SEKME1",
                    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.document))
            .setContent(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Sekme1Activity.class)));

    tabhost.addTab(tabhost
            .newTabSpec("tabindis2")
            .setIndicator("SEKME2",
                    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.music))
            .setContent(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Sekme1Activity.class)));

    tabhost.addTab(tabhost
            .newTabSpec("tabindis3")
            .setIndicator("SEKME3",
                    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.delete))
            .setContent(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Sekme1Activity.class)));

    tabhost.addTab(tabhost
            .newTabSpec("tabindis4")
            .setIndicator("SEKME4",
                    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.close))
            .setContent(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Sekme1Activity.class)));



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

  }
```

I read from some links that this is a problem adroid 4.0 and later. What can i do for setting icon on a tab.

Comment: First of all, you are using deprecated methods. When you do this, they are deprecated because you should be doing things differently in the new versions (use fragments instead of activities).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls try setView to set TextView instead of  setIndicator.
Set icon and indicator text to TextView.